# Type error inside and outside Section

Tags: coq

I have a function "`HF`" has type inside section `S`

```
Open S.
HF: forall f : dup_sig Sig, dup_ar f = ASignature.arity (F f)
End S.

Signature: Type
Sig: Signature    
dp_Sig : Signature
dup_sig : Signature -> Signature
F : dup_sig Sig -> Sig
dup_symb : Signature -> Type
dup_ar : forall Sig : Signature, dup_symb Sig -> nat
ASignature.arity : forall s : Signature, s -> nat
```

I want to write a lemma:

```
Lemma incl_fl : forall R R, Fl HF R [= R'.
```

Where

```
Fl: forall (S1 S2 : Signature) (F : S1 -> S2),
       (forall f : S1, ASignature.arity f = ASignature.arity (F f)) ->
       list (ATrs.rule S1) -> list (ATrs.rule S2)
```

It is Ok when I have this function inside the section `S`.

But I would like to write the function `incl_fl` outside the section `S`.
Here is the type of `HF` outside section `S`.

```
HF: forall (arity : symbol -> nat) (f : dup_sig (Sig arity)),
    dup_ar f = ASignature.arity (F f)

Lemma incl_fl : forall arity R R', Fl HF R [= R'.
```

I got an error at "`HF`" :

```
The term "HF" has type
 "forall (arity : symbol -> nat) (f : dup_sig (Sig arity)),
  dup_ar f = ASignature.arity (F f)" while it is expected to have type
 "forall f : ?35524, ASignature.arity f = ASignature.arity (?35526 f)".
```

I tried to find a place to add the `arity` in this function "`HF`", but I don't success. 
Could you please help me write the lemma "`incl_fl`" outside the section `S`? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
Lemma incl_Fl : forall arity R R', Fl (HF (arity:=arity)) R [= R'.
```